# Expo Dockerized App is not refreshing changes

Tags: react-native, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, expo

I'm dockerized an Expo React Native app so anyone of my team partners could download the repo and then make a docker-compose up and without effort have the same expo server running in their computers.
The problem is that changes aren't shown in Expo Go.

I checked that the files inside the container are being updated, and I also verified that the Expo Go app has fast refresh activated. I also confirmed that if I run the project locally, the refresh works. So, the problem must be in my Docker configuration.

My Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
COPY app.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install -g expo-cli

EXPOSE 8081
EXPOSE 19000
EXPOSE 19001
EXPOSE 19002

CMD npm i -f && npm start
```

```
version: '3.8' # Specify Compose file format version
services:
   expo: # Name of the frontend service
      container_name: expo-container
      build: ./ # Specify the directory of the Dockerfile
      ports:
         - 8081:8081 # Specify port-forwarding
         - 19000:19000 
         - 19001:19001
         - 19002:19002
      volumes: # Mount host path in the container
         - ./:/usr/src/app
         - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      environment:
         - EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0 
         - REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.0.2
```

Comment: Your image doesn't seem to actually contain the application code.  Just given what you show, it's not obvious how Docker helps your setup.  Can you and your teammates just install Node on the host system and use that directly?